# Connecting filebeat to elasticsearch using docker: Connection refused

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, filebeat

I am new to the forum as well as elk stack. I tried setting up the elk stack using docker.I was successful and then I added filebeat to the compose file. Ever since, the filebeat is causing a problem connecting to other containers. Initially, I configured it to send logs to logstash but after all the troubleshooting, when I still was not able to make filebeat talk to logstash, I completely removed logstash and tried connecting filebeat directly with elasticsearch. After doing everything I could , when I check for the logs of the filebeat container , all I see is **"Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://elasticsearch:9200)): Get "http://elasticsearch:9200": dial tcp 192.168.128.2:9200: connect: connection refused"**
When I check for indices in elasticsearch , I see filebeat there.
Also I'm able to ping to elasticsearch from within the filebeat container(Same with logstash, I was able to ping logstash from within).

Even after removing logstash from the stack, I still see logstash indices in elasticsearch. No idea why!

Please guide me as to where I'm going wrong.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

This is my filebeat.yml

````
    ``` filebeat.inputs:
         - type: docker
           containers:
             path: "/usr/share/dockerlogs/data"
             stream: "stdout"
             ids:
               - "*"
             cri.parse_flags: true
             combine_partial: true
             exclude_files: ['\.gz$']
        processors:
         - add_docker_metadata:
             host: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
        filebeat.config.modules:
          path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
          reload.enabled: false
        #output.logstash:
           #hosts: ["logstash:5044"]
        output.elasticsearch:
          hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
          username: elastic
          password: changeme
        log files:
        logging.level: error
        logging.to_files: false
        logging.to_syslog: false
        logging.metrics.enabled: false
        logging.files:
          path: /var/log/filebeat
          name: filebeat
          keepfiles: 7
          permissions: 0644
        ssl.verification_mode: none
        setup.kibana:
          host: "kibana:5601"
    ```
````

This is my elasticsearch.yml

````
    ``` ---
     ## Default Elasticsearch configuration from Elasticsearch base image.
     ## https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/distribution/ docker/src/docker/
     ## config/elasticsearch.yml
     cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
     network.host: 0.0.0.0
     http.port: 9200
     #network.host: 142.93.218.7
     ## X-Pack settings
     ## see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-xpack.html
     #
     xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
     xpack.security.enabled: true
     xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: true
    ```
````

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      # Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks.
      # see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elk

  #logstash:
    #build:
      #context: logstash/
      #args:
        #ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    #volumes:
      #- type: bind
        #source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        #target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        #read_only: true
      #- type: bind
        #source: ./logstash/pipeline
        #target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        #read_only: true
    #ports:
      #- "5000:5000"
      #- "9600:9600"
      #- "5044:5044"
    #environment:
      #LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    #depends_on:
      #- elasticsearch
    #networks:
      #- elk

  filebeat:
    build:
     context: filebeat-docker/
     # args:
       # ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    # Run as 'root' instead of 'metricbeat' (uid 1000) to allow reading
    # 'docker.sock' and the host's filesystem.
    user: root
    #ports:
    #- "5044:5044"
    command:
        # Log to stderr.
      - -e
        # Disable config file permissions checks. Allows mounting
        # 'config/metricbeat.yml' even if it's not owned by root.
        # see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/config-file-permissions.html
      - --strict.perms=false
        # Mount point of the host’s filesystem. Required to monitor the host
        # from within a container.
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/containers:/usr/share/dockerlogs/data:ro
      #- /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:ro
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      #- logstash
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    external: true
```

These are the filebeat container logs:

```
2021-07-26T08:54:34.833Z        ERROR   [publisher_pipeline_output]     pipeline/output.go:154  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://elasticsearch:9200)): Get "http://elasticsearch:9200": dial tcp 192.168.128.2:9200: connect: connection refused
2021-07-26T08:54:56.139Z        ERROR   [publisher_pipeline_output]     pipeline/output.go:154  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://elasticsearch:9200)): Get "http://elasticsearch:9200": dial tcp 192.168.128.2:9200: connect: connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting network.host in your elasticsearch.yml to 127.0.0.1 (in case you have everything on the same machine) or to your machine's IP ?

Comment: First of all, thank you for replying. Yes, I did try both the options. The outcome was the same, infact for 127.0.0.1, elasticsearch container itself was not reachable. It showed connection refused let alone not being able to connect from other containers.
As for my ip address, everything worked and was reachable but the filebeat logs showed "connection refused".

Answer (score 0):

In the ***elasticsearch.yml*** you can set the hostname with ***network.host: localhost***.

Set it to the IP address of your Host or the name of your docker service